# Why doesn't React render JSON?

Tags: reactjs

I have a JSON:

```
{
    "books": {
        "book1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Sample",
            "author": "Somebody",
            "genre": "Tales"
        },
        "book2": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Winter",
            "author": "Ted"
        }    
    }
}
```

I import it in a component:

```
import data from './books.json';
```

And then try to display it on a page:

```
class Home extends Component {
    render(){
        const carNode = () => {
            return (
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{data.books.book1.id}</th>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            <Link
                            to={"books/"+data.books.book1.id}

                            key={data.books.book1.id}>
                            {data.books.book1.name}                         
                            </Link>
                        </p>
                        <p className="author">{data.books.book1.author}  </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>               
            )
        };

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid content-main">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xl-12">
                        .........
                        <p>{carNode}</p>  
                        .........                                          
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But this code does not fill my table with data. Code worked fine when json was right in my index.jsx. I also installed and tried to use json-loader. Could you tell me what code should be used here?

Comment: what's the value of `data` inside `render()`? `undefined`?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't debug React. Console does not throw any errors.

Comment: Then you are not calling `carNode()`. Use  `<p>{carNode()}</p>` instead of  `<p>{carNode}</p> `

Comment: {carNode()} - it is OK. Are there any special methods in React to loop through JSON to show all the books?

Answer (score 0):

You declared it as a function, but you don't call it as a function:

```
<p>{carNode()}</p>
```

Comment: Yes I declared as as an anonimous function, but I do not know how to do it right.

Comment: You want to loop through each book?

Comment: I want to show in a table all books as links: book 1, book 2 etc. Clicking a link detailed info should open.

Answer (score 0):

why are you storing it as JSON? you need to export in order to import. you can do something like

```
export default {
 "books": {
    "book1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sample",
        "author": "Somebody",
        "genre": "Tales"
    },
    "book2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Winter",
        "author": "Ted"
    }    
 }
}
```

and change your file from a .json file to a .js

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
const carNode = Object.keys(data.books).map(item => 
        {return (
            <tr>
                <th>{data.books[item].id}</th>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <Link
                        to={"books/"+data.books[item].id}

                            key={data.books[item].id}
                        >{data.books[item].name}</Link>
                    </p>
                    <p className="author">{data.books[item].author}</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        )}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a json loader to import the json into your component.
[import a Json file in a React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129727/import-a-json-file-in-a-react-component).

Or, you can use a javascript object instead of json and import that into your component. Like:

```
// books.js
export default {
  "books": {
    "book1": {...},
    "book2": {...},
  }
}
```

Now, you can import it in your component:

```
import data from './books'
```