# React import json data

Tags: reactjs, vega

I draw a graph by using react vega. When i write config for the graph it works. I would like to get config in json format from an external file 
**barChartConfig.json**

I try to import this file but did not work. My question is how can i import a json and assign it into a variable?

```
import config from './barChartConfig.json';

const barSpec = config;
const Vega = ReactVega.default;

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            spec: barSpec
            // ,data: barData
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <Vega spec={this.state.spec} />

            </div>
        );
    }
}

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(<App />, app);
```

Comment: Is the JSON file stored locally or on a server?

Comment: it is on my local

Comment: can you `console.log(config)` and post the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [import a Json file in a React Component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129727/import-a-json-file-in-a-react-component)

Answer (score 0):

When you use this:
`import config from './barChartConfig.json';` it means you are "asking" your bundler (webpack?) to include the data of this file when it creates the `bundle.js` file.
Of course you will need an appropriate loader for that like `json-loader`.
If you are trying to get this data on run time then you will need to get it via ajax request. (fetch, axios etc...)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using create-react-app, `json-loader` will be already included. In that case you can use the following statement to load json file.

```
var config = require('./barChartConfig.json');
```